# Зацикливание ошибки в выводе Apache Tomcat в NetBeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

Пытался сделать в проекте один главный контроллер (сервлет) который бы обрабатывал все запросы к веб-приложению. 
Создал сервлет с url-pattern `"/*"`.
 В самом сервлете использовал RequestDispatcher`для перенаправления к другим сервлетам и`.jsp `. Но из этого получился лишь бесконечный цикл в котором совершался переход сервлет ->`index.jsp`-> сервлет->.. (либо сервлет->сервлет ..)
и апач написал что`StackOverFlow`. Я исправил код , запускаю и все те же ошибки. Я вообще удалил сервлет, сделал прямой доступ а ошибки при запуске проекта остались, причем он указывает на ошибку в удаленном сервлете.
Пробовал пересобирать проект, очищать но все без толку.

Как мне "восстановить" апач чтобы дальше можно было работать?
P.S ошибка выводится не один раз а пока не отключишь апач

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ) 
Оказывается либо NetBeans либо сам tomcat выводили эту ошибку из файла .log 
что в tomcat/log ) Удалил логи и ошибок этих нет)

P.S из-за этого вывода ошибок (которых по сути нет) все очень сильно тормозило.